# recursively move files from subfolders to another folder with vbscript

Tags: file, recursion, vbscript

I need to recurse a folder and all subfolders and move the pdf files to another folder. Looking here I tried the below but it seems to continuously run (the script never ends) but it does move the files.

I would also like to count the source files, recurse folder and move pdf (ignore case) files, count destinations files. If source and destination are equal then run dir *.pdf > trust.csv and send a success email

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Message = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set shell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")


'Specify variables for Emails
strScriptServer = "ASFOXTECHOPS01"
strScriptPath = "\\techopspc01\c$\scripts\WM..."
strScriptName = "[WM-01]-WMScansToCenterDoc.vbs"
'strToEmail = ""
strCCEmail = ""
strCCEmailFail = ""
strProcessID = "[WM-01]"
strCustomerImpact = "LOW"
strCorporateImpact = "LOW"
strDocumentation = "\\FSCHAFOX01\GROUP_SHARE\Tech Group\Documentation\Automation\"
blnEmailNotification = false

'Specify variables for File Paths
'strFromPath1 = "\\fschauni01\GROUP_SHARE\Wealth Management\Scanning\ZAstrosky\"
strToPath1 = "\\fschauni01\GROUP_SHARE\Wealth Management\Tech\"
strToArchive1 = "\\fschauni01\GROUP_SHARE\Wealth Management\Scanning\" & StrYear & "_" & strMonth

'BROKE************CREATE ARCHIVE FOLDER IF IT DOES NOT EXIST
'If FSO.FolderExists(strToArchive1) Then
        'Proceed
'Else
'       FSO.CreateFolder("\\fschauni01\GROUP_SHARE\Wealth Management\Scanning\" & StrYear & "_" & strMonth)
'End If

'DELETE FILES FROM THE strToPath(s) TO AVOID OVERWRITE ERRORS
FSO.DeleteFile (strToPath1 & "*.*")

testfolder = "\\fschauni01\GROUP_SHARE\Wealth Management\Tech\"
MoveFiles fso.GetFolder("\\fschauni01\GROUP_SHARE\Wealth Management\Scanning\ZAstrosky")
blnEmailNotification = True 

'Email
'If Err <> 0 Then
'   blnEmailNotification = false
'   HandleError
'End If     

If blnEmailNotification = True Then
            'Send Results email
            objMessage.Subject = "SUCCESS - " & strProcessID & " - WM Scanned Reports Imported into CenterDoc"
            objMessage.From = "IT Automation"
            objMessage.Sender = ""
            'objMessage.To = strToEmail
            objMessage.Cc = strCCEmail
            objMessage.TextBody = "---------------SCRIPT SUCCESSFUL---------------" & vbnewline & VbCrLf & "Script successfully moved the files with no errors." & vbnewline & vbcrlf & "- Script Name:" & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & strScriptName & VbNewLine & VbCrLf & "- Script Origination:" & VbTab & VbTab & strScriptServer & VbNewline & VbCrLf & "- Script Path:" & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & strScriptPath & VbNewLine & VbCrLf & "- Documentation:" & VbTab & VbTab & strDocumentation & VbNewLine & VbCrLf & "- Set1:" &VbTab & VbTab & "Souce Files = " & sourcecount1 & VbTab & VbTab & "Destination Files = " & destcount1 & VbTab & VbTab & "Archive Files = " & archivecount1 & VbTab & VbTab & "------------------------------------------------------------"
            objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
            objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = ""
            objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
            objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update
            objMessage.Send
Else
    'Do Nothing
End If

Sub HandleError
    strErrorMessage = "Error Number " & Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description 
    objMessage.Subject = "SCRIPT ERROR - " & strProcessID & " - IMMEDIATE ACTION REQUIRED"
    objMessage.From = "IT Automation"
    objMessage.Sender = ""
    objMessage.To = strToEmail
    'objMessage.Cc = strCCEmail
    objMessage.TextBody = "---------------SCRIPT ERROR---------------" & vbnewline & VbCrLf & "Script Name:" & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & strScriptName & VbNewLine & VbCrLf & "Customer Impact:" & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & strCustomerImpact & VbNewLine & VbCrLf & "Corporate Impact:" & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & strCorporateImpact & VbNewLine & VbCrLf & "Error Description:" & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & Err.Description & vbnewline & VbCrLf & "Error Number:" & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & Err.Number & VbCrLf & VbNewLine & "Script Location:" & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & strScriptServer & VbCrLf & VbNewLine & "Script Path:" & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & strScriptPath & VbNewline & VbCrLf & "Documentation:" & VbTab & VbTab & strDocumentation & VbNewLine & VbCrLf & "-------------------------------------------------"
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = ""
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update
    objMessage.Send
    Err.Clear
End Sub

Sub MoveFiles(fldr)
For Each f In fldr.Files
    basename  = fso.GetBaseName(f)
    extension = fso.GetExtensionName(f)
    If LCase(extension) = "pdf" Then
        dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, f.Name)
        Do While fso.FileExists(dest)
            dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, basename & "." & extension)
        Loop
        f.Move dest
        End If
    Next
       For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
         MoveFiles sf
    Next
End Sub
```

Edited original code for more help.
thanks Zoyd

astro

Answer (score 0):

You move all the pdf files from `\\fschauni01\GROUP_SHARE\Wealth Management\Scanning\ZAstrosky` and its subfolders to `\\fschauni01\GROUP_SHARE\Wealth Management\Scanning\ZAstrosky\Tech`. Your recursion logic is sound, but there is another problem: your destination folder is a subfolder of your source folder. Thus, your script keeps copying files from `\\fschauni01\GROUP_SHARE\Wealth Management\Scanning\ZAstrosky\Tech` to itself. Whether this works or not, it is a bad idea to do a foreach loop on a collection and modify its content.

The main problem is that this while loop will never end if it is taken at all, and in this case, it is taken. When your recursion reaches the destination folder, all the files already exist in the destination folder (obviously), the loop is taken and there is no way out of it.

```
If LCase(extension) = "pdf" Then
    dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, f.Name)
    Do While fso.FileExists(dest)
        dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, basename & "." & extension)
    Loop
    f.Move dest
End If
```

As for the matter of counting files, does `folder.Files.Count` not work ? (if you need a recursive count, I'am afraid you'll have to do it yourself, but you know how).

After your edit, the code still contains this:

```
Do While fso.FileExists(dest)
        dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, basename & "." & extension) ' ☠
Loop
```

So, for example, if a file a.pdf exists in `"\\fschauni01\GROUP_SHARE\Wealth Management\Scanning\ZAstrosky\docs1"` and in `"\\fschauni01\GROUP_SHARE\Wealth Management\Scanning\ZAstrosky\docs2"`, your script will find that a.pdf already exists in the archive directory and enters the infinite loop. A way around this is to recreate the directory structure in the archive directory (each time you call MoveFiles on directoryA, create directoryA in the archive directory and move files there).

Comment: Thank you Zoyd. I do see it now. Fresh eyes are always a wonderful thing

Comment: I still seems to have a loop. I moved the Tech folder up - so now -

testfolder = "\\fschauni01\GROUP_SHARE\Wealth Management\Tech\"
MoveFiles fso.GetFolder("\\fschauni01\GROUP_SHARE\Wealth Management\Scanning\ZAstrosky")

and I took out the miscellanous counts from the sub

Comment: Sub MoveFiles(fldr)
        For Each f In fldr.Files
            basename  = fso.GetBaseName(f)
     extension = fso.GetExtensionName(f)
     If LCase(extension) = "pdf" Then
           dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, f.Name)
         Do While fso.FileExists(dest)
   dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, basename & "." & extension)
         Loop
         f.Move dest
          End If
        Next
         For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
            MoveFiles sf
        Next
    End Sub

Comment: If it still doesn't work, you should edit the question and post the new code. It would be difficult to answer otherwise.